# Is there a way to conditionally set the y scale in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I'm using facetgrid to plot a few sets of data with Seaborn.

My columns are "Parameter1" which contain categories "A" and "B".
My rows are "Parameter2" which contain categories "1" and "2"

Ax1 and Ax2 are both best plotted with a linear scale. Bx1 and Bx2 are best plotted with a log scale. Is there any way for me to conditionally set yscale for log or linear depending on my Parameter1? I've tried searching for a good way to do this, but haven't been able to figure something out. Sorry, still a novice.

An example of my code is below. Any help is appreciated!

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,col="parameter1", row="parameter2", 
                  hue='Conditions', sharex=True, height=6, aspect=2, 
                  margin_titles=True)

(g.map(sns.lineplot, "x_values", "y_values", marker="o", err_style="bars", linewidth=5, 
       markersize=13))
g.set(xlim=(0,40), xticks=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40], yscale='log')
```

Comment: `g.axes[0,1].set_yscale("log")`?

Answer (score 0):

The .set_yscale("log") was not recognized as a function for me (maybe a versioning issue?). However, you really helped me in terms of understanding how the axes information was formatted. I ended up using this.

```
for x in range(3):
    g.axes[x,1].set(yscale="log", ylim=(0.001,1.2))
```

Comment: `g.axes[0,1].set_yscale("log")` works well in any version.